# What grammatical elements are contained in the sentence 你不听不就得了?

Tags: translation, grammar

A book on function words contains the example sentence:

管他说什么呢， 你不听不就得了。

The first part is simple: 管他说什么呢 = "no matter what" s.o. says (管 as conjunction). The second part however is unclear to me. Is there some special pattern, complement or whatever contained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The components are:

- 你不听: "you don't listen", of course.
- 不就 ... (吗): colloquial element, "isn't just that...?", "nothing other than..."
  (analyzed into 就 + rhetorical question)
- 得了: colloquial element, "fine with it", "enough"

Put all together:

> 你不听不就得了(吗)
>   lit. *You don't listen to him, then isn't it just fine?*
>   *"Why don't you just ignore him!"* or *"Is there any problem with ignoring him?"*